# Red Herring Redherring

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, metapuzzles

### Red herring redherringredh

[image: Red herring redherringredh]

---

### Redherri ngredh

[image: Redherri ngredh]

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Red herrIng red HErrING reD heRring Red herRing rED herrINg | REDHERRING |
> | rEd HErring reD HerRing Red hERriNg Red herring Red HerrIng rED hErrInG reD HerrIng rED herRInG red herRInG Red herRiNG reD herRiNG reD herriNG Red hErrING rEd herrinG red herRing rED heRriNG reD hErRInG Red HERring | ??? |

---

### Red herr ingre

[image: Red herr ingre]

---

### Redh erring

[image: Redh erring]

> |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | R | E | D | H | E | R | R | I | N | G |
> | R | I | I | H | H | R | H | D | R | G |
> | R | N | D | G | H | I | G | N | G | D |
> | D | D | I | H | D | D | N | D | D | N |
> | E | E | G | R | H | D | I | G | R | D |
> | N | D | D | H | E | N | D | N | E | R |
> | N | G | E | R | H | I | R | N | H | E |
> | E | I | I | D | I | N | E | E | I | R |
> | N | H | N | E | E | G | H | N | N | I |
> | G | I | G | N | R | D | D | N | R | N |
>
> **HEN** *GENE* *HIND* IRED **REND** *HINGE* NEIGH REIGN *GIRDED* **HERDING**

---

### Redherri ngre dherringr

[image: Redherri ngre dherringr]

---

### "Red" herr ingred

> **"Redherr" - Red Herrin, 1978**
>
> Redherr
> Ing red'h erri ng red he rri $\color{red}{\textbf{RED}}$ ngred
> Herri ngre dhe rrin
> Gre dhe'r ring re dher ring redh er rin gredh
>
> Redherr
> Ing red'h erri ng redh erri ngred herring
> Redh err ingredh err ingre
> Dhe rri'n gred he rr'i ngred he rr in'g red

> **"Redh Erri Ngr Edhe Rr In" - Redher Ringr, 2017**
>
> R edh'e rrin gred herrin gredh
> Err'i ngre dher ringre dherr
> Ing redh err ingr ed herr
> In gre dher, ri, N gre'd herr ing
> R edh'e rrin gred herring redhe
> Rri ngr edher ring red her
> Rin gred her rin gre dher
> Rin'g redh, er, R ing'r edhe rri (Ng!)
>
> Red H err ingredh, E rri ngredh er rin gred he rrin
> Gredh, E rrin gr edhe rri ngre, D he rr ing red herr
> I'ng red h erri ng redhe rri ngred he rr $\color{red}{\textbf{RED}}$, ingredherr
> I ngred he rrin, gred H errin gr edher, in!

> **"Redh E Rringredh Errin" - Redhe Rringredh, 1967**
>
> R edh errin gr edher
> $\color{red}{\textbf{RED}}$ ringr edh
> E rri ngre dherr
> Ing re dhe rri
> Ngr E dherr in gredhe
> Rrin g redherrin gredh
>
> R edh errin gr edhe
> Rri ngredh er ringr
> Edh erring redherr ing
> Red herr ingred herri
> Ngr E dherr in gredhe
> Rrin g redherrin gredh

> **“Re Dher’r Ingre Dhe Rrin” - Redhe Rrin, 1989**
>
> Redhe Rringr, Edher Rin, $\color{red}{\textbf{RED}}$ Gredh, Erringr Edh
> Errin Gredher, Ringr Edherrin, Gre DhErring
> Red HeRringr, Edherri Ngred, Herringred, Herringred
> Herri Ngred, Herri Ngred, Herring Redher

> **"Redh Erri Ngre" - Red Herring (redh. Errin Gredh), 2017**
>
> Redher, ringre dhe rringr edhe rr ingr
> Edh'e rrin gredhe rri ngredhe R rin'g redh
> E rrin gre dherr in gredherr
> I ngred her ringr ed herri ngr edhe
>
> R'ed herrin gredh er ring redh erri
> Ngre dher ring
> R'ed herrin gredh er ring redh erri
>
> R edhe (R ring) red herr (ing redh)
> Er ringr edhe rr ing $\color{red}{\textbf{RED}}$
> Red herri (ngr edher), ringr edher (ringr edher)
> Ri ngredher ri ngred herr
> I ngre dh errin gre dherrin gred
> Herri ngredh errin gred he rrin

[image: "Red" herr ingred]

---

### Red Herring "Redherri Ngredh"

[image: Red Herring "Redherri Ngredh"]

---

### Red herri

[image: Red herri 1]
[image: Red herri 2]

---

---

## Red Herring Redherring

[image: Red Herring Redherring]

Comment: Tell me - are there any red herrings in this puzzle?

Comment: @bobble Mayyyybe... ;-)

Comment: Ooh, exciting! I have a guess as to some of the inspirations behind this puzzle.

Comment: Puzzles like this make me wish I didn't have to go to work today!

Comment: All the cream of the crop is here!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### (Part 0 [hints])

> The titles for each puzzle provide hints for the minipuzzles. However, we only have the enumerations of the titles. It's likely not really possible to guess the helpful ones before solving the associated puzzles, but if you were to somehow do so you could use them as hints.
>
>  The minipuzzle titles are:
>  1. "Red Herring Identification"
>  2. "Baconian cipher"
>  3: "Red flag parts"
>  4: "Word search"
>  5: "Aquarium grid deduction"
>  6: "Red song lyrics"
>  7: "Sue Grafton Alphabet Titles"
>  8: "Red candy"
>  9: "Red Herring Metapuzzle"

---

### Part 1 [pictures of fish]

> These are all fish species (*OP note: in fact, they are all species of herring*): the big fish give the number of letters in their common names, and the small fish give the number of letters in their scientific names.
>
>  The species are:
>  1: DOGTOOT**H** (CHIROCENTRODON BLEEKERIANUS)
>  2: ARAUC**A**NIAN (STRANGOMERA BENTINCKI)
>  3: ATLAN**T**IC (CLUPEA HARENGUS)
>  4: RED**E**AR (HARENGULA HUMERALIS)
>  5: BLUE**S**TRIPE - (HERKLOTSICHTHYS QUADRIMACULATUS)

### Part 2 [weird capitalization]

> The text here is encoded with a Bacon cipher, where lowercase letters are A and capital letters are B. Decoding the longer string this way gives "MAGISTRATE OF GENOA, OR MEMED SHIBA INU (FOUR), to which the answer is **DOGE**.

### Part 3 [flags]

> These are the red portions of the flags of ETHIO**P**IA, PO**R**TUGAL, MALDIV**E**S, **P**ANAMA, MOZ**A**MBIQUE, and SE**Y**CHELLES, spelling **PREPAY**.

### Part 4 [word search]

> Each of the three different types of word in the word list (bold, italic, underlined) appears to trace out a letter when you tilt your head 45° to the left.
>  [image]
>  Ordering from light to dark, the letters are **FOX**.

### Part 5 [grids]

> These are Aquarium logic puzzles.
>  [image]
>  The solved puzzles spell out **ONE**.

### Part 6 [lines of text]

> These are lyrics to songs with the word RED appearing in them at the marked points; the bold text at the top gives the enumerations of the title and singer, as well as the year of release.
>  1: Roxanne, by The Police (1978)
>  2: Look What You Made Me Do, by Taylor Swift (2017)
>  3: What A Wonderful World, by Louis Armstrong (1967)
>  4: We Didn't Start The Fire, by Billy Joel (1989)
>  5: Play With Fire by Sam Tinnesz (feat. Yacht Money) (2017)
>
>  The words coming after the REDs in the lyrics are **L**ight, **U**nderlined, **R**oses, **C**hina, and **H**ot.

### Part 7 [diagrams]

> The first diagram is depicting RICOCHET. Puzzle veterans may recognize this word from the title of [Sue Grafton's *Kinsey Millhone* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinsey_Millhone), which all have titles like *"A" is for Alibi*, *"B" is for Burglar*, and so on.
>
>  The other four diagrams depict SILENCE, UNDERTOW, INNOCENT, and TRESPASS, which gives the answer **SUIT**.

### Part 8 [candy]

> The candies are:
>   - Gobstopper [×1]
>   - Twizzlers [×8]
>   - Sour Patch Kids [×2]
>   - Starburst [×6]
>   - Skittles [×8]
>   - Swedish Fish [×3]
>  Indexing into the candy names by the number of appearances gives **GROUSE**.

---

### Part 9 [meta]

> The left side is the "red" meta. Four answers can be fit into this grid so that the letters marked with red can be replaced with the string `RED`:
>  **F**OX → **RED**OX
>  D**O**GE → D**RED**GE
>  HAT**E**S → HAT**RED**S
>  PREPA**Y** → PREPA**RED**

> The right side is the "herring" meta. It appears that each of the other four answers is a synonym of a type of fish:
>  ONE → S**O**LE
>  SUIT → TAI**L**OR
>  LURCH → FLOUN**D**ER
>  GROUSE → C**A**RP

> Reading both "red" and "herring" letters for each of the four rows, and spacing the pairs as indicated gives **FOOLED YA** - a perfect ending for a puzzle released on April 1!

*Thanks to Stiv, Gareth, and samm82 for correcting a few errors and helping to finish off the puzzle.*

Comment: Your answer here contains pretty much everything I've managed to solve for myself, plus part 7. Where I can help you is: rot13(Gur svefg fbat vf Ebknaar ol gur cbyvpr. Sbe guvf fho-chmmyr, lbh arrq gb gnxr gur svefg yrggre bs gur jbeq sbyybjvat 'ERQ' - guvf tvirf lbh Yvtug-Haqreyvarq-?-Puvan-? juvpu vf yvxryl gb fcryy YHAPU be YHEPU. Lbhe zvffvat pnaql vf FGNEO[H]EFG - gurer ner 6 bs gurz.)

Comment: I think your missing one in the meta is likely [TAILOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluefish), which is an alternative name in AUS/NZ.

Comment: Also, I'm sure you've already noticed it even though you haven't mentioned it explicitly, but all of the 'Redherring' titles are just placeholders for other appropriate titles of the same length: rot13("Erq Ureevat Vqragvsvpngvba", "Onpbavna pvcure", "Erq synt cnegf", "Jbeq frnepu", "Ndhnevhz tevq qrqhpgvba", "Erq fbat ylevpf", "Fhr Tensgba Nycunorg Gvgyrf", "Erq pnaql" naq "Erq Ureevat Zrgnchmmyr") - may be worth using those in the brackets after each 'Part #' divider in your answer :)

Comment: Wow, what a nice write-up! The sub and final answers are correct, of course, and to help you with "Red herring redherringredh," rot13(gur svfu ner nyy ureevatf gung unccra gb or erq).

Comment: Possible fish for part one: rot13(qbtgbbgU - Puvebpragebqba oyrrxrevnahf, tnyncNtbf - Bcvfgubarzn oreynatnv, nGynagvp - Pyhcrn unerathf, erqRne - Unerathyn uhzrenyvf, oyhrFgevcr - Urexybgfvpugulf dhnqevznphynghf) - only issue here is with the second one; it's common name is one letter too short to fit in the blank, which might mean a typo in the question, or that it isn't the intended answer.

Comment: The last song is rot13(Cynl Jvgu Sver ol Fnz Gvaarfm "srng. Lnpug Zbarl", naq gur jbeq nsgre "erq" vf "ubg". Juvpu qbrf, nf rkcrpgrq, ortva jvgu U.)

Comment: Everything is now essentially correct - the one fish that @samm82 was unsure about is an rot13(nenhpnavna ureevat, fpvragvsvp anzr *Fgenatbzren oragvapxv*.) Also, rot13(nyy gur svfu va gung chmmyr ner ureevatf, urapr gur gvgyr "Erq *ureevat* vqragvsvpngvba.") Great work everyone!

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer:**

> One of the sections appeared to be flags with all colours apart from red removed. After a little bit of digging, I found that the flags, in order of appearance are:
>  ethio**P**ia, po**R**tugal, maldiv**E**s, **P**anama, moz**A**mbique and se**Y**chelles.

Then,

> Transposing the letters of the countries onto the fish below each flag, and taking only the red herrings, we get the word **PREPAY**!

Not sure if this has anything to do with the puzzle or if I've stumbled upon a red herring, but I hope this answer helps somebody!

Answer (score -2):

**Partial Answer:**

> When you solve Redh erring, you will see this:

> [image]

The yellow ones mean light red,
Red means the same,
And Dark red as the same.

Let's do something:

> What if we make a thing in the gaps of all the words we spotted, like this:

> [image]

(I used a solver, so don't sue me)
What does it mean? What does the shape resemble?

That's all I have!

Comment: So the answer isn't a compound bow?

Comment: This really isn't a [significant partial answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6706/69582); you haven't even solved one part of a multi-part puzzle. Please refrain from posting partial answers unless you can make substantial progress. See linked meta post. (Unrelated: please also use correct spelling and grammar. It's I not i, etc.)